# What determines the published message on a topic

Tags: ros, rostopic, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made 2 msg file. In one msg file I have 4 variables and in the other I have an array to that message

Files are as follows. This is car.msg

```
  int32 id
  int32 width
  float64 height
  float64 speed
```

The second file which is just an array to the cars is as follows. cardata.msg

```
  car[] mycars
```

I am opening a master node in one terminal and then I am launching another node in another terminal then through `rostopic echo /topic_name` I am publishing data.

I want to know what determines the data published. I have succeeded in publishing data which is like this:

```
id: 21
width: 1
height: 1.05549145701
speed: 0.385172053253

id: 22
width: 1
height: 1.057
speed: 0.394
```

and it keeps on going recursively for till id =50. id starts from zero till 50.

I want to publish this data only when my id is an even number so in this case the id=21 will not be published. How can I do that. Which files determine what is being published. msg file generated .h files and other files. I have tried to change the .h files (car.h and cardata.h in my case) to change the output but it does not work. The same message is published. Can you tell me how can I change this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67634/what-determines-the-published-message-on-a-topic/) by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 729 on 2013-07-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on 2013-07-18**:
@DirkThomas if you can help me with this. I have tried my best to figure this pety problem but could not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your code determines this. So you need to look in your code and only publish, when you want to. This is not a ROS issue.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-18**:
You can also publish data (even one for example) and not take it in account when you receive it (your subscriber must then not take into account any received data with an even id).